# Upper bound for the norm of the inverse of a particular symmetric positive-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, upper-lower-bounds

For a matrix $A$, by $||A||$, I mean the matrix-norm induced by the $\ell^2$-norm. Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times p}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $D\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ with $||A|| < 1$. Define,
$$
N_k :=
\begin{cases}
CA^{k - 1}B, &\text{if }k \geq 1\\
D, &\text{if } k = 0\\
0, &\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
I need an upper bound for $\|(N_k^{\sf{T}}N_k)^{-1}\|$ in terms of the norms of the aforementioned matrices. Are there any useful results that may help me achieve this?

Comment: If, say $m < p$ or $n < p$, $N_k^TN_k$ cannot even be invertible. So there surely has to have more conditions for this?

Comment: @DavidGao, I have the additional constraints that $B\neq 0$ and $C\neq 0$. Can you provide an example of your situation? Will assuming $\operatorname{rank}{[B, AB, A^2B, \cdots , A^{m - 1}B]} = m$ resolve this?

Comment: Any arbitrary $A, B, C$ with $m < p$ or $n < p$ would do, just write down any matrices with those constraints on their sizes. And no, assuming those conditions on ranks would not be enough. $N_k^TN_k$ is a $p$-by-$p$ matrix. For it to be invertible, $N_k$ has to have rank $p$, so $A$ and $B$ have to have rank $p$ (in particular, $m \geq p$) and $C$ has to have rank $p$ (in particular, $n \geq p$).